# PyGame: my image isn't appearing

Tags: python, pygame

I've written a code and I'm trying to get my image to appear at the center, but when I run it the image doesn't appear at all, any ideas of where I went wrong?

(btw I tested different codes and the images load fine, so there isn't anything wrong with python or pygame themselves)

```
from __future__ import division
import math
import sys
import pygame


class MyGame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
        pygame.init()

        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

        self.bg_color = 0, 0, 0

        self.alien_img = pygame.image.load('alien.png')
        self.alien_pos = ((self.width-rect.width)//4,
                          (self.height-rect.height)//4)


        self.FPS = 30
        self.REFRESH = pygame.USEREVENT+1
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.REFRESH, 1000//self.FPS)


    def run(self):
        running = True
        while running:
            event = pygame.event.wait()

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            elif event.type == self.REFRESH:
                self.draw()

            else:
                pass # an event type we don't handle            

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)

        rect = self.alien_img.get_rect()
        rect = rect.move(self.alien_pos)
        self.screen.blit(self.alien_img, rect)

        pygame.display.flip()


MyGame().run()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Just a tip: the `else: pass` part does nothing.

Comment: pixshi could you have a look at my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to move:

```
rect = self.alien_img.get_rect()
```

To the init before the following line:

```
self.alien_pos = ((self.width-rect.width)//4,
                      (self.height-rect.height)//4)
```

And after:

```
self.alien_img = pygame.image.load('alien.png')
```

The following is your code with the changes to put the picture in the frame:

```
from __future__ import division
import math
import sys
import pygame


class MyGame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
        pygame.init()

        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

        self.bg_color = 0, 0, 0

        self.alien_img = pygame.image.load('alien.png')
        rect = self.alien_img.get_rect()
        self.alien_pos = ((self.width-rect.width)//4,
                          (self.height-rect.height)//4)
        self.FPS = 30
        self.REFRESH = pygame.USEREVENT+1
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.REFRESH, 1000//self.FPS)


    def run(self):
        running = True
        while running:
            event = pygame.event.wait()

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            elif event.type == self.REFRESH:
                self.draw()

            else:
                pass # an event type we don't handle            

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)

        rect = self.alien_img.get_rect()
        rect = rect.move(self.alien_pos)
        self.screen.blit(self.alien_img, rect)

        pygame.display.flip()


MyGame().run()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Before you where trying to access rect before it had been defined. I've added a picture of the window created below:
[image: the screen]

Will point out that your plan to get this picture in the middle isn't working to do that you would need to change:

```
self.alien_pos = ((self.width-rect.width)//4,
                      (self.height-rect.height)//4)
```

To:

```
self.alien_pos = (self.width//2 - rect.width//2,
                  self.height//2 - rect.height//2)
```

Which gives the required results:

[image]

Comment: If you use screen's rect, you can do `alien.rect.center = screen.center` or if not defined, then `alien.rect.center = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().center`